# Comma placement after [greeting] and a [term of endearment]

Tags: punctuation, commas, hypocorisms

Long-time lurker, first-time poster.

When addressing someone with a term of endearment and a greeting, how does comma placement work?
The reason why other questions didn't work in answering this was that they would never directly fix my predicament.

I understand that hypocorisms (not nicknames) are not capitalized as they are general. I don't understand if a greeting gets a comma *after* or *before* the name. Especially since, if it's before the name it looks like a non-essential clause.

For example:

Hey, pretty lady, you seem like fun.

Hey pretty lady, you seem like fun.

Comment: In your examples, I’d punctuate to my own rhythm. That is, they sound like speech, so I’d mimic the speaker's pattern. Welcome to ELU, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Hello, Alexis, welcome to ELU." In the sentence I just typed, I am addressing you (*Alexis*) directly. That is referred to as **direct address**, which is offset by commas when in the middle of a sentence. (See rules in link below.)

https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wrtps/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_c&page=9J8lRcRhJ-78.html

So, the placement of commas in the first sentence...

> Hey, pretty lady, you seem like fun.

...before and after the direct address ("pretty lady") is correct.

> Always use a comma when directly addressing someone/something,
>   regardless of whether the direct address is at the beginning or end of
>   the sentence. If the direct address is in the middle of a sentence,
>   use a pair of commas to set off the direct address.

http://www.grammarerrors.com/punctuation/commas-in-direct-address/

That being said, leaving commas out of greetings (with direct addresses in them) seems to be a common error that is, perhaps, becoming more prevalent.

**Example sentences:**

> Hey, honey, pass the honey.
>
> This chair goes over there, sweetie.
>
> Would you like a chocolate bar, little one?
>
> “Hey, buddy, pass the chicken.”
>
> “I’m distracting you, little turd blossom.”
>
> “Hey, dude, check out that chick.”
>
> “Hand over that phone, jerk!”

See #7: https://dianetibert.com/2015/03/09/when-to-capitalize-names-that-are-not-names/.

Some examples aren't so endearing. See more examples in the link below. Have a nice day.

https://www.thoughtco.com/vocative-grammar-1692598